# Variants of Martin's axiom

Tags: set-theory

Let P be the statement: Every ccc partial order has $\omega_1$-precaliber; i.e., every uncountable subset $X$ of a ccc partial order $P$ has an uncountable subset $Y$ such that for every finite subset $F$ of $Y$, there is a member in $P$ below every member of $F$.

Let Q be the statement: Product of ccc partial orders is ccc.

It is known that $MA(\omega_1)$ (Martin's axiom at $\omega_1$) implies $P$ and that $P$ implies $Q$. Do these implications reverse?

Comment: The new tag does not belong here, so I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Todorcevic and Velickovic ([Martin's axiom and partitions](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1987__63_3_391_0.pdf)) proved $P$ implies $\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$.

Answer (score 6):

In a recent article of Teruyuki Yorioka it is stated that it is open whether Q implies
$\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$.
The reference is
[[A non-implication between fragments of Martin’s Axiom related to a property which comes from Aronszajn trees](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2009.02.006), Annals of Pure and Applied Logic. 161(4), p. 469-487].
I don't think the other implications are known either.